# "Show that $\{x_i...\}$ and $\{x_i+x_j,...\}$ are the same vector space." What is wrong with my proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm preparing for my Linear Algebra 1 exam, and I have come up with a proof of my own for the following exercise. When I went to check though, the "example solution" was totally different. I don't see what is wrong with my own solution, but there has to be. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Original Assignment: Let $V$ be a real vector space, $n \in \mathbb N$ with $n\geq 3$ and $x_1, ..., x_n \in V$ each different Vectors.

1. Show that $A=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $B=\{x_i+x_j \mid 1 \leq i < j \leq n\}$ produce the same subvectorspace of V
2. Prove or disprove: $C=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $D=\{x_i-x_j \mid 1 \leq i < j \leq n\}$ produce the same subvector space.

Now my solution to this is:

1. Let $b\in B$, then $b = x_i + x_j$

   1.1 $\iff b = \sum_{k=1}^n t_kx_k$ with $t_i=t_j=1$ and $t_{\neq i,j}=0$

   1.2 $\iff b \in span(A)$

   1.3 $\iff A = B$
2. With $t_i=1$ and $t_j=-1$ yes.

The original solution:

1. Obviously $span(B) \subseteq span(A)$. Otherwise let $i\in\{1,...,n\}$. Because of $n\geq3$ there exist $j,k \in \{1,...,n\}$, so that $i,j,k$ are each different. Therefore:

   1.1 $x_i = \frac 12(x_i + x_j) + \frac 12(x_i + x_k) - \frac 12(x_j+x_k) \in span(B)$
2. (a lot of typing, but basically a "there exists so that this is false".

My biggest issue is that I don't understand the original proof, particularly where the $\frac 12$ come from. Can you show me what I did wrong in my proof, and where the $\frac 12$ come from? Thanks.

Comment: There must be something missing, or we have a counterexample $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ generate a different subspace than $(1,1)$.

Comment: "$\cdots+\frac12(x_j+x_k)$" is wrong and should be "$\cdots-\frac12(x_j+x_k)$". The statement $\text{span}A=\text{span}B$ needs an extra condition to be true: $n>2$. You proved that $\text{span}B\subseteq\text{span}A$ but not the other side. For that you must write elements of $A$ as a linear combination of elements of $B$. This can be done and at that point $\frac12$ comes in.

Comment: The "original solution" uses the assumption that $n≥3$ which isn't present in the statement.  Did you leave it off?  Worth noting that the claim is certainly false if $n=2$.

Comment: @drhab and lulu: I fixed those mistakes, you were right. Noah I think you got confused because of the missing $n\geq 3$, right?

Answer (score 1):

With your answer to your first part, you have showed that any $b \in B$ is in the span of $A$.  This allows you to conclude that $B \subseteq span(A)$, so that $span(B) \subseteq span(A)$.  However, you must *also* prove that $span(A) \subseteq span(B)$; it is this more challenging direction that you have skipped.

Your incorrect answer to 2 exemplifies the mistake in your thinking.  Consider 
$$
x_1 = (1,0,0) \quad 
x_2 = (0,1,0) \quad
x_3 = (0,0,1)
$$
As before, we find that $span(D) \subseteq span(C)$, as you have correctly showed.  However, the reverse inclusion fails to hold in this case.  In particular, 
$$
span(D) = \{(a,b,c):a+b+c = 0\} \subsetneq span(C) = \Bbb R^3
$$